# Devise, Rails-API, Routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

I have the following routes setup inside a rails api app:

```
  constraints subdomain: 'api', path: '/' do
    namespace 'api', path: '/' do
      scope module: 'v1' , constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
        devise_scope :user do
          post   'sign_in'  => 'sessions#create'
          delete 'sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy'
        end
        resources :question   
      end
    end
  end


  # rake routes
  Prefix Verb          URI Pattern            Controller#Action
  api_sign_in POST     /sign_in(.:format)     api/v1/sessions#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
  api_sign_out DELETE  /sign_out(.:format)    api/v1/sessions#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

When I got to execute this test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::V1::SessionsController, :type => :controller do


  describe '#create' do
    it 'creates a session' do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = User.create(email: 'rob@edukate.com', password: 'password')
      post :create, action: :create, user_login: { password: user.password, email: user.email}

      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end

end
```

I get this error:

```
F

Failures:

  1) Api::V1::SessionsController#create creates a session
     Failure/Error: post :create, action: :create, user_login: { password: user.password, email: user.email}
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       Could not find devise mapping for path "/sign_in?user_login%5Bemail%5D=rob%40edukate.com&user_login%5Bpassword%5D=password".
```

I have tried many variations of routes but I cannot get this simple test to pass. If I cannot get it completed like this I'll just roll my own Auth; but it appears devise is doing something odd with a Abstract controller. Thanks in advance!